# Sitecore using Glass mapper and MVC

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

Hi am using the Glass mapper in combination with Sitecore MVC. I created model below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Test
{
    using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes;

        [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
        public class GlassTestModel
        {           
            public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

this is my view

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<Test.GlassTestModel>
<div>
<h2>Hello</h2>
<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
</div>
```

I also tried this first line

```
@model Test.GlassTestModel
```

and this one

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Test.GlassTestModel>
```

I created a view rendering in Sitecore.  configured the model to use above.
When I render the view the model fields don't get filled. When I test in a controller I use for other controller view like below:

```
ISitecoreContext ctx = new SitecoreContext();
var item = ctx.GetCurrentItem<Test.GlassTestModel>();
```

I do get the title field. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try to inherit from `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView` only?

Comment: Which version of Glass Mapper? If you're using V4 then you can simply use `@model Test.GlassTestModel` without the inherits statements.

Comment: The other 2 are onlu there to show what i tested with. But you mean only this rule @inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView without <>? . How will it then now wich model class to choose? Or is that passes from SiteCore? I am using v3

Comment: I only added from nuget and started. Should i edit config inlcudes or edit GlassMapperScCustom.cs?

Comment: Have you tried `var item = ctx.GetCurrentItem<GlassTestModel>();` in the controller?

Comment: var item = ctx.GetCurrentItem<GlassTestModel>(); works. But i don't have a controller rendering I want to use a view rendering with automapping of my fields

Comment: If you starting a new project then recommend V4 since the older version will become unsupported. Make sure you installed the correct implementation: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glass.Mapper.Sc/

Comment: http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial12 <-- ensure your view rendering has the namespace and class name in it like in the tutorial. Without that it'll not map.

Comment: I created a new MVC project for my sitecore site. I added Glass Mapper V4 from NuGet. Still no result in my view.

Comment: @DannyH, can you try adding your assembly that contains the Model to Glass's attribute loader class that exists under App_Start? I wonder if you need to notify Glass of the assembly for view mapping to occur..?

Comment: Add the assembly to `App_Start/GlassMapperScCustom.cs` to the `GlassLoaders()` method similar to this: http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial20

Comment: Hi. I tested my project on a new SiteCore instance and there it does work with V4. V3 however still won't automap. In V3 I also don't see te getmodel  pipeline in the config so does automap even work in V3?

Comment: Yes, it works in V3 http://www.glass.lu/Blog/AutoMapping so not sure why it is not working. If you are not already tied to V3 then I recommend you use V4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I migrated my solution to V4 of the Glass.Mapper package. This works. With V3 I can't get the automapping to work.